# How can I find out which Bluetooth codec is being used between Ubuntu and my audio devices?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, codecs

I want to check that Ubuntu is using the best available codecs to communicate with my Bluetooth audio devices. How can I find out which codecs are being used?

Comment: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) or "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP). Check the sink at the sound settings.

Comment: So what do I need to do exactly? Do I need to open a particular app to get this information? The main Ubuntu sound settings only tell me the name of the device. I have Sound Switcher Indicator installed, but that only tells me the name of the device and its Bluetooth address.

Comment: hmmm I expected the sink to be shown there (my system does ;) but ... the tool to install is pavucontrol. It will list anything you want about sound.

Comment: Thank you!

pavucontrol indeed has this information. It is under the "Configuration" tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the used [Bluetooth Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/?types=adopted&keyword=Profile&filter=):

- *Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)* profile uses a low sound quality codec (CVSD) optimized for speech
- *High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)* speaks for itself :)

Look under Settings / Sound / Output tab:
[image: screenshot of Settings / Sound / Output]

Or you may install `pavucontrol` (PulseAudio Volume Control) and check under the Configuration tab:
[image: screenshot of pavucontrol / Configuration]

Comment: H/T @Rinzwind whose comments helped a lot to come up with this answer